# No Errors When Helpers Not Included in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in CakePHP and following its blog tutorial. I was trying not to write / include the helpers and components in the controller **PostsController** and found the blog running well without warnings or errors. **PostsController** uses helpers and components like this

```
public $helpers = array(’Html’, ’Form’, ’Session’);
public $components = array(’Session’);
```

While the index view use Html helper to create a link as `$this->Html->link()`. Is this ok to use helper without any declaration or usage call? How is the right way to use helper or component in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Cookbook's page on HTMLHelper:

"The HtmlHelper is available in all views by default. If you’re getting an error informing you that it isn’t there, it’s usually due to its name being missing from a manually configured $helpers controller variable."

The same applies to Form Helper, and I believe Session Helper and Session Controller.  The only reason to add them to the $helpers and $components properties is that if they are never loaded, you can't use them, and you'll get errors.